# Conjunction Problems on since

Tags: conjunctions

1)Since i was unwell ,so i did not come.

2)Since i was unwell ,i did not come.

> My book said sentence 1 is not correct as we don't use **so with since**.
>   Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use *so* with *since*: *I haven't been to the restaurant since,* ***so*** *I don't know what its food is like now.* It's just wrong in your particular sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence (1) is incorrect. I don't think the explanation "we don't use *since* with *so*" explains that much, though.

The sentence is incorrect because it doesn't have a main clause. The word *so* is a coordinating conjunction that connects two main clauses, and the word *since* is a subordinating conjunction that introduces a dependent clause. You can't make a complete sentence by using a coordinating conjunction to connect a dependent clause to a main clause.

> *Because I was unwell, and I did not come.
>   *Though I was unwell, but I came anyway.

are incorrect sentences for exactly the same reason. You need to get rid of one of the conjunctions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, "we don't use **so** with **since**" simply means the sentence can do either without *since* or without *so*.

In other words,

> I was unwell, so I did not come.

(without *since*) would also be correct.